# how to set pdf cover page margins in laravel 5.2 with snappy pdf wkhtmltopdf

Tags: pdf, laravel-5, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I am using Laravel 5.2 with with snappy pdf wkhtmltopdf.

I need to make pdf with cover page. 
My code is ::

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadHTML($view->render());
       $pdf->setOption('cover', View::make('generatereport.pdfcoverpage', $dataArray));
        $pdf->setOption('margin-top',0);
        $pdf->setOption('margin-bottom',10);
        $pdf->setOption('margin-left',0);
        $pdf->setOption('margin-right',0);
        $pdf->setOption('footer-html',  View::make('generatereport.pdffooter'));
```

the Problem is 'margin-bottom' is applying on Cover page which I dont want.
How can I apply all `margin = 0` to cover page ?

I direct ask to https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/182
but there is no-reply.

Comment: This is problem with wkhtmltopdf https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2282